# Any workaround to use PHP SoapClient with a local WSDL file (NON-URI)?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have an application running in CLI mode on a server that neither has nor needs to run a local httpd. The application does outgoing interactions with a web services provider using SOAP. The provider in question has some availability issues and we are trying to reduce the number of issues by hosting the WSDL file locally at their suggestion.

It seems that the SoapClient constructor (in WSDL mode) can only make use of a URI WSDL file, but I am trying to figure out some way to work around this limitation and have it read the WSDL file from the local filesystem in some way. I am surprised that the SoapClient constructor does't have an option to pass a filename or a string of text which I could have simple read in prior.

Has anyone got a suggestion on how to sidestep this limitation and do what I am attempting?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[`SoapClient()`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) takes a URI which supports not only web addresses, but local file paths.  But relative paths aren't working here, so it needs to be the full file path.

Here's how to load a local WSDL file with a relative reference. If the WSDL is in the same directory as the current PHP file:

```
new SoapClient(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'the.wsdl.xml');
```

or if it's in a subfolder of the current PHP file:

```
new SoapClient(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'subfolder' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'the.wsdl.xml');
```

or if it's in a parent folder of the current PHP file:

```
new SoapClient(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'the.wsdl.xml');
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've tested and confirmed that with absolute paths this does work. I feel like a fool for having missed it. I am sure I tried 'filename.wsdl', './filename.wsdl' but not absolute. *facepalm*

Comment: Be sure to set file permissions correctly if you're hitting this from apache.