# WSDL-File is never Found but exists (is found with other ext)

Tags: php, nginx, soap, wsdl, http-status-code-404

I've written a SOAP-Application with PHP, which works pretty good on my local PC. I need a WSDL-File to parse my request but the Server give me a 404-Error for the WSDL-File.
On my local Server where I use an Apache, it works - I can also access the File with my browser eg: http://localhost/myfile.wsdl

On the Production-Server where a NGINX-Webserver is there I get everytime a 404 Not found error, even if I try to access that file from my Browser. (Also on cURL) But if I rename the file to eg .txt then I CAN access it. So its not an typo in the filename or so

This is weird may I have to change any config or so? It never let me access WSDL-Files

Comment: Seems that the file extention WSDL is blocked by the server. If the renamed version work, why not using the renamed version. WSDLs must not end with `.wsdl` to work. You need only a valid URI like http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/.

Comment: Also you can do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157000/any-workaround-to-use-php-soapclient-with-a-local-wsdl-file-non-uri#23568967