# How to provide SOAP API policy/extension requirement in the SOAP client

Tags: php, api, soap

i need to connect to a soap api ... now i've been working with soap api couple of times before but since 99% api are rest now it's been years since i've worked with them

when i call the api using soap client i get

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Unknown required WSDL extension 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy'
```

so when i open the wsdl address in my browser (login/password protected) i can see these lines in the xml output

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:p1="urn:haixin:all2crm" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="SI_USBPC_REQUEST" targetNamespace="urn:haixin:all2crm">
<wsdl:documentation/>
<wsp:UsingPolicy wsdl:required="true"/>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OP_SI_USBPC_REQUEST"/>
```

and down somewhere i have

```
<wsp:Policy>
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#OP_SI_USBPC_REQUEST"/>
</wsp:Policy>
```

when i search this error i can only find 1 resource in the whole internet and the answer is to turn off the policy requirement ie : `<wsp:UsingPolicy wsdl:required="false"/>` but i dont own the api so thats out of question also when i search the policy name `OP_SI_USBPC_REQUEST` i get no result so im guessing this is some custom name set by api owner

so my question is should i produce the policy and attach them to the soap client request ?
what is the connection between the policy and extension since im getting extension missing error but it would go away if i turn off the policy requirement

are extensions downloadable from somewhere ? whats the format ... and should i attach them to the soap client request ?

or it's something that should be installed on the server ? would error go away if i somehow add the extension since im already attaching username/password to api call or is that just the first step and should i handle the policy requirement after that ?

btw  im using php to call the api and here is my code

```
    $options = [
        'login' => 'mlogin',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
    ];

    $client = new \SoapClient("http://domain:port/dir/wsdl/?p=sa/92130e1ffa97338ba2d1fc026567031d" , $options );
```

if i download the xml and turn off the requirement on my local file and use that file address in the soap client can i use the file to talk to the api ? (my understanding is the xml doesn't contain any actual data and it's just a interface/definition for soap client and i cant use my local file to talk to the online api or maybe im wrong ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message "Unknown required WSDL extension " means that SoapClient found an element outside
of the WSDL namespace with the `wsdl:required` attribute set to `true`
(as you can see [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f6c9a90e19d648355c39da84af9bc59b2ff60c15/ext/soap/php_sdl.c#L211)).

So, to avoid the error, one way is to set the `wsdl:required` attribute to `false` indeed.

It is perfectly possible to download the WSDL file, modify it and use the local copy. Just make sure to use the
absolute path, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23568967/12763954).

By the way, "policy" in this context refers to the [WS-Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Policy) specification.

Comment: thanx whats the point of this `element outside of the WSDL namespace ` ... does that mean i should call the api with some parent/higher level url or something which has this element in it's namespace ?

Comment: @max No, just disable `wsdl:required` in the WSDL and it should work.